# SwifUI update the navigationBarItems title based on condition

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I like to update a navigationBarItems title based on certain condition, I am using below code.

Here currentpage state is getting updated, but navigationBarItems title not getting updated.

```
@State private var currentPage = 0
var pages: [MyPage]

var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
          //Here current page value is getting updated
       PageView(currentPage: $currentPage)
    }
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Text(currentPage == pages.count ? "Done" : "Skip"))
}
```

Comment: Should actually be updated. Are you sure that the condition should not be `currentPage + 1 == pages.count`?

Comment: Updates for me.

Comment: Yes did a small mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use total count - 1, try below code

```
 @State private var currentPage = 0

 var pages: [MyPage]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
              //Here current page value is getting updated
           PageView(currentPage: $currentPage)
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Text(currentPage == pages.count - 1 ? "Done" : "Skip"))
    }
```